# C++ std::vector<std::string> iterator segfaults

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, iterator

I encountered this segfault while iterating through a vector of filenames. The std::vector is populated by another function reading csv in a pretty messy code. So I narrowed it down to the below code causing the problem.

The iterator for vector segfaults after yielding first (sometimes later) item  of the vector with 4 items. Pushing the 5th item fixes the problem. Strange? Iterator for vector works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<int> popbar() {
    // populate vector of integers
    //
    std::vector<int> bar;

    for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        bar.push_back(i);

    return bar;
}

std::vector<std::string> popxar() {
    // populate vector of strings
    //
    std::vector<std::string> xar;

    xar.push_back("one");
    xar.push_back("two");
    xar.push_back("three");
    xar.push_back("four");
    // this line fixes segfault
    //xar.push_back("five");

    return xar;
}

void foo () {
    // yield next vector item
    //
    //auto bar = popbar();
    auto bar = popxar();

    //static auto itx = bar.begin();
    static vector<string>::iterator itx = bar.begin();

    if (itx == bar.end()) {
        cout << "end of line" << endl;
        itx = bar.begin();
    }

    cout << *itx++ << endl;
}

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        foo();
    }
}
```

The expected output is

```
one
two
three
four
end of line
one
two
three
four
end of line
one
two
three
```

The output I get is

```
one
Segmentation fault
```

also seen

```
one
two
three
Segmentation fault
```

and

```
one
three
three
���1������������1one1fourSegmentation fault
```

if that makes it more interesting. Does it? Please consider this for vector as well .

Comment: Looks like there is a memory corruption, can you enable gflags and run it through the debugger

Comment: Just curious, what's your reasoning behind making `vector<string>::iterator` a static variable in the `foo()` function in the first place?

Comment: I really like the final set of output. Illustrates undefined behaviour quite perfectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You defined a **static iterator** to a **local variable**. What did you expect was going to happen?

When `foo` returns, the local vector `xar` is going to get destroyed, which invalidates all your iterators. Re-entering `foo` creates a brand new vector, and then you try to use an invalid iterator. Undefined behaviour ensues.

Comment: Okay I missed that, thanks. But then how come it is working for vector<int> as defined, consistently!? Also for vector with five items. Really confused.

Comment: @user1480788 - `But then how come it is working for vector<int> as defined, consistently!?`  Also stated as *`Why when I do this obvious illegal construct, my program works?"*  When you do something like this in C++, the behvior is *undefined*.  Being "undefined" means anything can happen, including work, fail, work today fail tomorrow, work on your computer but fail on another computer, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have a `static` iterator pointing into a non-static local variable. When the `foo` function returns, `bar` is destructed. This leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).